# Git error: after reset and there will a few file left and can't push on GitHub or Commit

Tags: git, github

**The result show like this**

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/NickcoDamian/HTML-Fundamental.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**Can't do commit**

```
git commit -m "update file"

On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I want to know why I can push the files on GitHub after I did reset the files and I can't do commit the files.

Comment: You need to run `git pull` first. Someone else commited in the first time, you need to merge your changes and their changes first

Comment: `git pull --rebase` is the standard way to resolve this. This will pull the latest commits from your repo and move your local commit after those commits in the history.

Comment: You talk here about "reset[ting] the files" but `git reset` is not about resetting files (it has that as a *side effect*, but it's about moving branch names and resetting Git's *index*). You should clarify precisely what you did *before* you got to this state.